# How to return the 3 most and 3 less frequent numbers out of a list, elegantly

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to use underscore for this, but for some silly reason it escapes me:

I have a list of numbers:
39, 39, 10, 1, 3, 4, 5... etc

I want to return the 3 most frequent and the 3 less frequent.

I've tried using _.countBy but that somehow returns an object, which makes it hard (?) to sort, unless perhaps I'm missing the obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First this groups them without parameters (just creates new arrays with each having the same value), and then sorts them by the resulting array lengths.  Then creates two new arrays of min and max, using the first three and last three elements.  `.map` is used to return only the first element instead of the array created by `.groupBy`.

**EDIT**: This is Benjamin Gruenbaum's slicker edit of my original answer.

```
var arr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,9,8,9,8];
var group = _.sortBy(_.groupBy(arr), "length");
var min = _.pluck(group.slice(0, 3),0);
var max = _.pluck(group.slice(-3),0);
console.log(min);
console.log(max);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymDhm/)

Comment: Nice alternative solution +1, I made some slight modifications if you feel like it. Namely Underscore includes a `pluck` method, and `slice` accepts negative indices. http://jsfiddle.net/X6Ka9/ http://jsfiddle.net/ymDhm/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum feel free to improve.  I never heard of underscore before today.

Comment: Another fun fact, JS is really fast in modern browsers, http://jsfiddle.net/mLEdx/ here it is on one million elements. Runs in ~ 2 seconds.  (Mine, which is also pretty slow does 500 miliseconds http://jsfiddle.net/zmvE4/ , an efficient one probably does a lot less)

Comment: Thank you - gave you the vote because you were the closest to a very lean solution with that fiddle that uses _.pluck(). Beautiful thing, thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum did that fiddle! (oh well, Ben I +1ed yours too).

Answer (score 9):

Call me crazy, but here is a solution without underscore, it's not particularly fast since I sort which takes `O(n log n)` instead of searching for the maximal three which is `O(n)` but if it really matters I can fix it.

Let our array be:

```
var arr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,9,8,9,8]
```

First, we reduce the numbers to their frequencies:

```
var t =arr.reduce(function(a,b){
    a[b] = (b in a) ? a[b]+1 : 1; // set to 1 if not there, else increase
    return a; // return the object
},{});

var res = Object.keys(t).sort(function(x,y){ // sort by frequency
   return t[x] > t[y]; 
});
// Res more generally contains the frequencies ordered
alert(res[0]+" "+res[1]+" "+res[2]);
```

#### [Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/D25cF/)

Ok, so I lied - I'm a sucker for native JavaScript, here is the "easier" Underscore version:

```
obj = _.countBy(arr,function(num){return num; }); // get array by frequencies
var res = _.keys(obj).sort(function(x,y){ return obj[x] - obj[y]});
//res is now the same as above, to be honest I like the native version better :)
```

#### [Underscore fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kvk5f/) if that's your thing.